# Windows 10 update

Tags: windows-7

I don't have windows 10 yet and I don't want it. Says I might have problems with my connection to the internet. I have patches ready to download and am afraid that it will have it hidden in there. I have a Dell AMD Inspiron and it isn't configured to handle windows 10. I'm afraid to download the patches. I'm not having any problems now but I know I will have to download the patches. I don't know which ones to download.

Comment: So what is your question?  What patches?

Comment: Normal windows patches. I was afraid windows would hide the win 10 in them somewhere. I know I panicked. I don't trust them at all.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [GWX Control Panel](http://ultimateoutsider.com/downloads/) which is a little utility which will make sure Windows 10 does not get downloaded and installed. It is kept up to date and I have heard good things about it. It was reviewed by Steve Gibson who is a well known security expert and he just mentioned it on his latest [podcast](https://twit.tv/shows/security-now).

Comment: I was lucky. I found that and had it on my computer. It is a wonderful program for people who don't want or like me for some reason can't have win 10. I guess that when my computer dies I will have no choice in the matter about getting it unless I go to Apple products. I have always liked Dell products. I  have had good luck with my Dell computers. This program was a godsend to me. Thanks for answering.